# Why is my else if code not running on a Server side? I want to get the input printed given number of times loop is running on client side

Tags: java, serversocket

MyServer.java

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  

public class MyServer {  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        try{  
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(5001);  
            Socket s=ss.accept();//establishes connection   
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
            String  str=(String)dis.readUTF();  
            System.out.println("message= "+str);  

            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
            if ("Hi".equals(str)){
                dout.writeUTF("How are you?");
            } else if ("Bye".equals(str)){
                dout.writeUTF("Thankyou! Have a Good day!"); 
            } **else if (str != null)){
                try {
                    String numbers;
                    numbers = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""); 
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
                     dout.writeUTF("The line is being printed"); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                            dout.writeUTF(str.replaceAll("[^a-z,^A-Z]", ""));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //TODO: handle exception
                }**
                
                 
            } else {
                dout.writeUTF("Sorry!");
            }       
            dout.flush();  
            dout.close();  
            s.close();  
            ss.close();  
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
    }  
}
```

MyClient.java

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
import java.util.*;  

public class MyClient {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
            Socket s=new Socket("localhost",5001);  
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            String str1= sc.nextLine();           
            dout.writeUTF(str1);  
            dout.flush(); 
            
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
            String  str=(String)dis.readUTF(); 
            System.out.println("message= "+str);

            dout.close();  
            dis.close();
            s.close();  
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);} 
    }  
}
```

I am giving input to the server from the client-side and want that input to be printed given a number of times on the client-side. But not able to do that. Can anyone let me know what mistake I am making here? It is replying to message "Hi" and "Bye", everything else is working fine.

Comment: You should do something with your exception, it's likely that you have an exception but since you don't log it, you don't know what is happening

Comment: @LeoG. It is "dout.writeUTF("The line is being printed");" , Till this line, it is working fine but after onwards it is not working, like it's not printing the output I want.

Comment: Why would `str` not be equal to `str` (if it isn't null)? Wouldn't this make it logically the same as an `else`?

Comment: @AndyTurner  yes you are right, corrected that part. but still not getting the output printed.

Comment: This `.replaceAll()` part seems non-sensical to me. What are you trying to accomplish by that?

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I am trying to store a number from input to a variable and using it in for loop, to run or print that output that number of times.

Comment: You only read 1 line in your client then you close the socket. So, the ones that you don't get are simply not read.

Comment: @rmfeldt what changes should I then make on the client-side to make it work.

Comment: @amnaa You'll probably won't get any numbers, when first replacing them all with an empty string.

Comment: @amnaa You client is a bit too simple to handle this case, but if you just want to verify it you could simply add a loop over the dis.readUTF()/println lines in your client. The client should receive an EOFException when the server closes the socket so you have to catch that.

Comment: @MartinZeitler then what should i do now?

Comment: @rmfeldt okay let me try this too.

Comment: @amnaa Your replaceAll will work, it is just not the conventional way of doing it and that is probably why Martin reacted to it. Keep in mind thought that a client message like "12 sends 12 hello" would give you a number of 1212. :) Normally you would probably define the message format so that you know the position of the number and parse it that way. Perhaps "12;write this" and then String.split(";",2) or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is your code with my corrections.
(Notes after the code.)

Class `MyServer`

```java
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5001)) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();// establishes connection
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            String str = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("message= " + str);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            if ("Hi".equals(str.trim())) {
                dout.writeUTF("How are you?");
            }
            else if ("Bye".equals(str)) {
                dout.writeUTF("Thankyou! Have a Good day!");
            }
            else if (str != null) {
                try {
                    String numbers;
                    numbers = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
                    dout.writeUTF("The line is being printed");
                    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                        dout.writeUTF(str.replaceAll("[^a-z,^A-Z]", ""));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            dout.writeUTF("END");
            dout.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException xInterrupted) {
            // Ignore.
        }
    }
}
```

Class `MyClient`

```java
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str1 = sc.nextLine();
        try (Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5001)) {
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF(str1);
            dout.flush();
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            String str = dis.readUTF();
            while (!"END".equals(str)) {
                System.out.println("message= " + str);
                str = dis.readUTF();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sending and receiving data via sockets is not instantaneous. Method `readUTF` will wait until there is data to read. It will read all the data sent in the last invocation of method `writeUTF`. Method `readUTF` will wait indefinitely. Hence the server needs to send notification to the client that there is no more data to send. In the above code I send the string **END** to indicate the end of the data that the server is sending. Note also that you only need to close resources that you explicitly create. In class `MyServer`, this means `ServerSocket` only. I use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that `ServerSocket` is closed.

Similarly, in class `MyClient`, the only resource that needs to be explicitly closed is the `Socket` – which I again do using *try-with-resources*.

If the server terminates, the socket is closed. Hence, in class `MyServer`, after sending data to the client, the server waits for two seconds which is hopefully enough time for the client to read that data.

Comment: Thank you for not just helping me out, but also for making my concepts clear. Your code worked.

Comment: one small question why we have used Thread.sleep(2000L); ?

Comment: @amnaa _why we have used Thread.sleep(2000L); ?_ See the last paragraph in my answer.